# Why is my jade so droopy?

Tags: houseplants, jade

My jade plant is very droopy. I keep it in my southwest facing window and try to keep it behind a few other plants to get filtered sun. I water once a week (if I remember -- let's just say it's definitely not overwatered). I've had it for several years, I can't even remember when or where I got it at this point. Here's a picture so you can see. It's never grown up, only down.

[image]

It also has these weird, as I call them, "fractal jade" formations. Instead of growing up it just sort of branches out.

I have another jade plant that grows perfectly upright and "normal" looking, and I treat these two the same, so I'm not sure what gives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably Kleinia petraea, the trailing jade plant, and not Crassula ovata, the upright jade plant. Care regime is the same, really, but its best planted in a hanging pot rather than a standing pot. I'd repot into a hanging pot which is just big enough to take the rootball it currently has - these don't need repotting very often.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was such a thing as trailing jade. Once I move I'll get it into a better container.